# Run junit without data source persistence context in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, junit

In my spring boot application, there is a persistent context class for data source connectivity. While I write junit for this application, it always call this configuration class and fails when database connection is off. The junit didn't run if I exclude this configuration class. What is the solution to run the junit,even the database connectivity fails.

Comment: Hi. Your solution is good. You must put all database configuration in a separate config class and then don't import it in you junit test class.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution for it?